# Export KendoGrid UI to Excel With Background Color in MVC

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, export-to-excel, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to export my KendoGrid to excel, my grid bind from dynamic object. I get the data from the database and store it to datatable and return the datatable to my view, so my grid column can be flexible.

My question is how to export my grid to excel along with cell style to excel?
i use html code for creating the grid not javascript code.

Thank You

Comment: That's not so simple. You will need to catch the `ExcelExport` event (add a JS handler) and explicitly set the background color. This basically means that you need to manually create all the rows which are to be exported, which is done by iterating the grid data source.

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not support HTML and for this reason breaks (br) cannot be translated to new row. On the other hand you could use an approach as mentioned on the given pages below:

[Configure Color for Alternating Rows](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/excel/alternating-rows) 
[excelExport](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-excelExport)

Hope this helps...

Comment: hi, i tried another way, and it worked, i use Epplus for creating excel file, i download it from NuGet package. I get the data from database, store it in datatable, and in my controller, write row by row in excel with the coloring.